# Discord.js fired several times

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi3, discord.js

The code that I made is fired several times, I have tried to add returns but it doesn't matter. I'm running the code with a raspberry pi 3.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.once('ready', () => {    
        console.log('Ready!')

})
client.on('error', console.error);



client.on('message', message =>{
    if (message.channel.id == '...........') {
            console.log(message.content);
    }
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ping`)) {

if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === '⚙️ | Manager')) 
{message.channel.send('Pong!');} else { 

message.channel.send('Not enough rights! :no_entry:');  

}}
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}test`)) {
if (message.author.id == '.........') {

const role = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'test');

message.member.addRole(role);
message.channel.send('test');

}}});
client.login(token);
```

I expect it to output it onces, but I don't get it to work.

[This is the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKEZO.png)

I want him to do it only once.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you be any more descriptive about the issue? Example outputs say. I think I can see the issue, but I need to know more to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I've had that problem before, simply turn off the bot from everything you're hosting it on, you were probably logged in on it multiple times, that might be because you're running it on a raspberry pi and did not properly shut it.

Comment: No problem, just always make sure you shut it correctly.